# Software to manage inventory/assets, allow rental/quote generator, workflow for event planning

Tags: workflow, inventory, planning, invoicing

I am looking for some software that can simplify our company's rental and event workflow.

Requirements:

- Web access with multiple users
- Ability to keep inventory of assets
  with different rental prices, asset tag numbers, custom fields?
- Ability to generate a quote based off of equipment ability to have a
  workflow for quotes and event planning (something like a kanban board
  showing status with a workflow for moving to the next category)

Preferred:

- Single payment, no monthly fees.  Can self host.  (open to monthly fees though if reasonable).
- Integrated Chat system (like slack)
- Ability to have an item, with multiple of the same item as a quantity for making a quote
- Calendar to show when equipment is in use
- Time tracking for employees
- Gmail and Google calendar integration for emailing clients

Some possibilities that I have been looking at are using microsoft exchange as it could show equipment availability if resources were used for each asset, but it lacks many of the other required features.  I am also looking at using Jira and it's companion applications.  It could easily handle the workflows, and simple asset management, but I believe it would have problems with assigning assets to events and generating the quotes.

For reference, we currently use in house custom software to manage quotes and assets, and slack for chat, but moving to a single integrated app would make our workflow easier and much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I work for Comindware - workflow management software vendor.

I'm not 100% sure that our workflow product - Comindware Tracker - will fit. However, we recently created pretty similar solutions with asset management, assigning assets to events and generating quotes for airline and software development company. I'd suggest to have a talk to Comindware sales managers - it is likely that they would help.